# MySQL query to get values based on same column

Tags: mysql

I am using Mysql database, Below is one of my table,

[image]

I want get Route id from above table based on the busstop id. For example i will pass the bus top id as 9 and 11. So i have to get route id which falls under these two bus stops. same time i shouldn't get route id if any one location is not exists. As in above table i shouldn't get 3 because 11 is not exists in that route 3. output as below

[image]
Any suggestions are welcome.
Regards
Sangeetha

Comment: can't understand what do u want ?

Comment: Can you please paste your output also, so that we can help you out... For eg. if you entered bustopid as 9 & 11 then what output you exactly want...

Comment: Output is added to the question. Thank you..

Comment: So the order in which stops occur is unimportant? 11,9 is the same as 9,11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use post aggregation filtering to check for both conditions

```
SELECT routeid FROM t GROUP BY routeid
HAVING SUM(bustopid=9)>0
AND SUM(bustopid=11)>0
```